MUI DateTimePicker resets itself when in SidePanel component
I'm having a problem with the DateTimePicker being inside a SidePanel in my project.
It resets itself when trying to type in a value.
(While creating the sandbox, it worked ONCE outside the SidePanel for some reason but then it didn't anymore)
In the pictures you can see the steps. It lets me type in the values but resets as soon as I put the first minute in.


Here is a codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/pk9pjd
I tried many things. Refactoring the whole function, checking the yup validation, disabling validation, trying outside the SidePanel
Thank you so much for helping!
